# PayPal 401 Client Authentication Failed in Sandbox environment with node js sdk

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, http-status-code-401

I've followed this guide https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/setup-sdk/ and this example https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Nodejs-SDK/

Here is my code:

```js
import paypalCheckout from '@paypal/checkout-server-sdk';

const environment = new paypalCheckout.core.SandboxEnvironment(
  'ACTUAL_CLIENT_ID_FROM_PAYPAL_DASHBOARD',
  'ACTUAL_CLIENT_SECRET_FROM_PAYPAL_DASHBOARD'
);
const client = new paypalCheckout.core.PayPalHttpClient(environment);
const request = new paypalCheckout.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();

request.requestBody({
  intent: 'CAPTURE',
  purchase_units: [
    {
      amount: {
        currency_code: 'USD',
        value: `100.00`
      }
    }
  ],
});

client.execute(request)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(`${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
    console.log(`${JSON.stringify(response?.result)}`);
  })
  .catch((executeError) => {
    console.log(`${JSON.stringify(executeError)}`);
  });
```

I get:

```
{
  error: HttpError: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/@paypal/paypalhttp/lib/paypalhttp/http_client.js:136:22)
      at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:388:22)
      at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1336:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
    statusCode: 401,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '77',
      connection: 'close',
      date: 'Tue, 29 Jun 2021 01:22:38 GMT',
      'cache-control': 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
      'paypal-debug-id': 'c2b.......c7a',
      'x-paypal-token-service': 'IAAS',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
    },
    _originalError: {
      text: '{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}',
      statusCode: 401,
      headers: [Object]
    }
  },
  message: '{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}'
}
```

I've searched Google and Stack Overflow but I only find similar issues about switching from sandbox to live.

My code isn't working in sandbox environment.

Comment: Include the actual client id and paypal-debug-id in your question. (If you are completely sure the credentials are from sandbox and not live, you can include the secret as well-- sandbox credentials are not sensitive)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. There is no trace of the API call nor of the paypal-debug-id. On the other hand, using the client id and secret with POSTMAN to get a token (https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token) and then making an actual request (e.g. https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders) everything works fine. I wanted to use @paypal/checkout-server-sdk

Comment: It appears in your question as `'paypal-debug-id': 'c2b.......c7a',`

Comment: I meant in the PayPal dashboard, under the API calls tab

Comment: Access token calls won't appear there even if successful. Anyway, the issue is your question doesn't have enough information to be of help--which is why I said what to include